# Summation for each number entity in a java list

Tags: java, list

I have a list in java, it contains 3 rows. It looks like below:

```
"InputForD3" :[
{"cashvalue":100,"cashInput":500,"profit":400},
{"cashvalue":100,"cashInput":500,"profit":400},
{"cashvalue":100,"cashInput":500,"profit":400}
]
```

now I want to have a sum-up at each entity level and maintain it as an object, something like below

```
"InputForD3" :[
    {"cashvalue":300,"cashInput":1500,"profit":1200}
]
```

I am stuck at this, cant think for a solution - how to approach ?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://ideone.com/ZYjLzb

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont provide the code, its hard to say where you stuck.

But generally, you can iterate over the list and sum each attribute separately and then construct the resulting object with collected sums.

here the link for inspiration how you could sum the numbers
https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-sum

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Summation of InputForD3 profit: "+List.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getProfit()).sum());
System.out.println("Summation of InputForD3 cash: "+List.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getCash()).sum());
System.out.println("Summation of InputForD3 cashInflow: "+List.stream().mapToInt(o->o.getCashInflow()).sum());
```

This is what I was looking for, Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `reduce()` function：

```
public class TripleInt {
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
}

    TripleInt tripleInt1 = new TripleInt(100,100,100);
    TripleInt tripleInt2 = new TripleInt(200,200,200);
    TripleInt tripleInt3 = new TripleInt(300,300,300);

   TripleInt reduce = list.stream().reduce(new TripleInt(0, 0, 0), (curr, temp) -> {
        return new TripleInt(curr.getOne() + temp.getOne(), curr.getTwo() + temp.getTwo(), curr.getThree() + temp.getThree());
    });

    System.out.println(reduce); //TripleInt(one=600, two=600, three=600)
```